# insert document in bulk using for loop mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Why this won't insert 20 document for me?

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
  const [updated] = await Promise.all([
    Job.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $set: {
          status: 'something'
        }
      },
      { upsert: true, new: true }
    ),
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      {
        $set: { assigned: true }
      },
      { upsert: true, new: true }
    )
  ])
}
```

or I should use reduce and Promise resolve? Above query worked just that it doesn't insert 20 documents, it inserted one document.

Comment: what is `id` and `userId` here?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet does it matter? my question is something else.

Comment: yes it does matter because you are upserting with same `_id` again and again which means it will create only one document and will do upsert it 20 times... so your loop does not make any sense here... Please try to understand what you have written in your query above

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I see, you're right, so how can I solve that? assume I don't mind to have the same `_id`? I just want 20 randomed field to test something.

Comment: yes then you can achieve this using bulkWrite query in mongodb

Comment: what's the different btw insertMany?

Comment: insertMany requires an array to insert multiple documents in the database but cannot update the documents... whereas the bulkwrite will update the documents with upsert as well... I am giving you an example of bulk write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have array of `id` then you can use [bulkWrite](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite)

```
const id = ['844646464', '45646546546', '45646546546']

Model.bulkWrite(
  req.body.idArray((id) => {
    return ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: id },
        update: { $set: { status: 'something' } },
        upsert: true
      }
    })
  })
})
```

It will create a request something like this

```
bulkWrite([
   { updateOne: { filter: { _id: id }, update: { $set: { status: 'something' } } },
   { updateOne: { filter: { _id: id }, update: { $set: { status: 'something' } } },
   { updateOne: { filter: { _id: id }, update: { $set: { status: 'something' } } } 
])
```

Which efficiently performs all updates in a single request to the server with a single response.